# Django: Custom function value not showing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-custom-manager

Trying to understand how to make custom functions in Django. I have the following:

models:

```
class OptionManager(models.Manager):
    def test(self):
        test = "test"
        return test

class Option(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    objects = OptionManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

view:

```
def questn(request, question_id):
    o = Option.objects.filter(question=question_id).annotate(num_votes=Count('answer'))
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'o':o})
```

test.html

```
{{ o.test }}
```

My page is blank, but it should display "test". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working is, the custom method should not be on manager, but on the model itself

```
class Option(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    objects = OptionManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    def test(self):
        test = "test"
        return test
```

Now, for what you are looking to do, it should be

```
{{ o.objects.test }}
```

Please note that this is the wrong usage of custom methods. Managers are normally used for custom filtering options.

Read more on the [managers here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#managers)